# How to match reqid in nftables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nftables

It seems linux already has a module for nftables nf_xfrm, which contains some code about reqid, however there is no description about it in man page.

So, how to translate the following command to nftables?

```
iptables -D FORWARD -s 10.0.0.1/32 -i eth0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*nftables* version, 0.9.0, was [released on 2018-06-08](https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/downloads.html#nftables-0.9.0), more than a year ago, and this feature is not available in this version. Only testing having been decapsulated is available.

**UPDATE**: [nftables 0.9.1 has been released](https://netfilter.org/news.html#2019-06-24) on 2019-06-24, so one can hope it will be packaged in one's favorite distribution soon.

Kernel support for additional handling of ipsec in *nftables* was added in version 4.20<sup>[1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.20-rc1&id=6c47260250fc6114ce2012db13e1cd3938a27b73)</sup>. On userland side, corresponding support for additional ipsec features [was](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=153613940916342&w=2) added in git master branches around 2018-09-21 for libnftnl <sup>[2](https://git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/commit/?id=43146d504c34003fe94389b0717c9f79c6de792d),[3](https://git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/commit/?id=f4621a6f870644af934869d52bf24137c76910db)</sup> and nftables <sup>[4](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=04ca9a6ba3ca369053e9b5951f2f85bf8fe98e72),[5](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=8f55ed41d007061bd8aae94fee2bda172c0e8996),[6](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=57c2b152c5f0866be5bf1acda2f341ba26ba9448)</sup>.

The last patch is what provides *reqid*:

> src: add ipsec (xfrm) expression This allows matching on ipsec
>   tunnel/beet addresses in xfrm state associated with a packet, ipsec
>   **request id** and the SPI.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> ipsec in ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24
> ipsec out ip6 daddr @endpoints
> ipsec in spi 1-65536
> ```

(Well there isn't an example for a request id, nor matching the underlying protocol which might not be implemented, see later)

So to be able to use this feature, currently at least this is needed:

- kernel 4.20
- libnft 1.1.2 or [1.1.3](https://netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/downloads.html#libnftnl-1.1.3)
- build *nftables* from [git source](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables). A [new *nftables* release is due to happen soon](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=155925099204614&w=2), but appears to be delayed for now.

If OP's *iptables* rule was an append rather than a delete (which currently can only be done in nftables by [using the *handle* keyword](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_rule_management#Removing_rules)) it should translate into this (including boilerplate):

```
nft add table ip filter
nft add 'chain ip filter forward { type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip filter forward ip saddr 10.0.0.1 iifname "eth0" ipsec in reqid 1 accept
```

I didn't add `meta ipsec exists` before `ipsec in reqid 1`: testing the *reqid* should require and thus test having already been subject to ipsec decapsulation.

What doesn't appear to be made available and not mentioned [in the documentation](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/doc/primary-expression.txt?id=01e5c6f0ed0315046537612f5a80e506d37a7f8e#n330) is the equivalent of  `--proto esp`, so I couldn't put it.

If matching the esp protocol is *really* needed, one can imagine that using a mark on the outer envelope packet should do it, knowing that the mark is preserved after decapsulation:

```
nft add table ip filter
nft add 'chain ip filter input { type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept; }'
nft add 'chain ip filter forward { type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip filter input ip protocol esp meta mark set 1
nft add rule ip filter forward meta mark 1 ip saddr 10.0.0.1 iifname "eth0" ipsec in reqid 1 accept
```

Disclaimer: take with a grain of salt, only the syntax was tested (using *nftables* from git commit [01e5c6f0ed0315046537612f5a80e506d37a7f8e](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=01e5c6f0ed0315046537612f5a80e506d37a7f8e)). This wasn't actually verified on IPSec. There's probably also a rule to add for 4500/UDP for UDP encapsulated ESP.

<sup>1 [netfilter: nf_tables: add xfrm expression](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.20-rc1&id=6c47260250fc6114ce2012db13e1cd3938a27b73)</sup>
<sup>2 [expr: rt: ipsec match support](https://git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/commit/?id=43146d504c34003fe94389b0717c9f79c6de792d)</sup>
<sup>3 [expr: add xfrm support](https://git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/commit/?id=f4621a6f870644af934869d52bf24137c76910db)</sup>
<sup>4 [src: rt: add support to check if route will perform ipsec transformation](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=04ca9a6ba3ca369053e9b5951f2f85bf8fe98e72)</sup>
<sup>5 [src: rename meta secpath to meta ipsec](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=8f55ed41d007061bd8aae94fee2bda172c0e8996)</sup>
<sup>6 [src: add ipsec (xfrm) expression](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=57c2b152c5f0866be5bf1acda2f341ba26ba9448)</sup>

Comment: Just curious, why don’t they release a new version after such long time?

Comment: The mail I link about tells: "There are a few bugs that are sorted out right now, a new release should happen soon once that is resolved."

Comment: 0.9.1 has been released on 2019-06-24